# How to fix this eslint path not resolved error? no-unresolved

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, eslintrc

Node version: `v6.11.0`

Error Message:

> Unable to resolve path to module './coins.json'. (import/no-unresolved)

I am also attaching a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Here you can see that App.js and coins.json live in the same root:

[image]

### .eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": "webpack"
  },
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/no-find-dom-node": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "document": true,
    "window": true
  },
  "env": {
    "jest": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  }
}
```

### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Routes from './config/Routes';
import { setSearch } from './actions';
import localCoins from './coins.json';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.setSearch(localCoins);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Routes />
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setSearch: (...args) => { dispatch(setSearch(...args)); }
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

### My webpack.config.babel.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import chalk from 'chalk';

const coinhover = path.resolve(__dirname, 'coinhover');
const app = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const log = console.log;

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: `${__dirname}/app/index.html`,
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

const ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'coinhover.css',
  disable: false,
  allChunks: true
});

const CopyWebpackPluginConfig = new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'app/static', to: 'static' }]);

const PATHS = {
  app,
  build: coinhover
};

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND;

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
});

const base = {
  entry: [
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), 'node_modules'] }
};

const developmentConfig = {
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'coinhover'),
    quiet: true,
    inline: true,
    compress: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    open: true
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
  ]
};

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    productionPlugin
  ]
};

log(`${chalk.magenta(' ')} ${chalk.italic.green('npm run:')} ${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND)}`);

export default Object.assign({}, base,
  isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
);
```

Comment: What node version do you use?

Comment: @TeoTN `v6.11.0` could that be it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Unable to resolve path to module './coins.json'. (import/no-unresolved)

In general `eslint` has no knowledge about `webpack` existence and some configuration, that provide some resources in bundling time, such as [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) and [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) mechanisms. Linter just check current folder structure, and if there is no target file, it causes a warning.
So, then using `eslint` with `webpack` build-time resolver resources, just add following ignore command: `// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved, import/no-extraneous-dependencies`.

Comment: Also this fixed my bigger issue `"rules": {
    "import/no-unresolved": [
      2,
      { caseSensitive: false }
     ]`